# Why wicket checkGroup won't check anything

Tags: java, wicket

I have two `List<String>` objects, **existingTableList** and **tableList**, a **`listview` with tableList** and a **`checkgroup` with existingTableList**. 
When existingTableList and tableList have same strings the checkgroup won't check them. How can i make the checkgroup check the same strings that the two List have.

```
ListView<String> tableListView = new ListView<String> ("tableListView",tableList) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
                        String it = item.getModelObject();
                        item.add(new Label("tableListLabel", it));
                        item.add(new CheckBox("checkbox", Model.of(Boolean.FALSE)));
                    }
 };
tableListView.setOutputMarkupId(true);  

CheckGroup<String> checkGroup= new CheckGroup<String> ("checkGroup", existingTableList);
checkGroup.add(tableListView);
checkGroup.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Check` component for `CheckGroup`.

`CheckBox` component should be used when there is no grouping.

P.S. I know it is really confusing. `Check` and `CheckBox` probably should be merged into one class and made it working in any case.